# how to filter jqgrid data

Tags: jqgrid, stack, filtering

```
 $("#open_data").click(function() 
{   
    var c = $("#dashboard_total_object_list_grid"),b = c.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");      
         b={filters: 
            {groupOp: "OR",
            rules: [
                { field: "state", op: "cn", data:"Open" },
            ],
        }}
  c.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
            postData:b,
            search: true,

    });

     c.trigger("reloadGrid");        
})
```

this is my code

My question is i want to filter my table based on state column where it has in database in following format

{state:Open }and {state:Close}

but column name in database is "parameters",in jqgrid table is "state"

when i run this code it display as "no records to display"

thanks for helping

Comment: {state:Open }and {state:Close}    i want to filter jqgrid table based on -Open- value  only when button cliclk

Comment: Where is performed the search - in server or at client side? Which version of jqGrid is used? If used server - what is the configuration e.g PHP/Apache, ASP.NET, Java,...

Comment: search is performed on server side and configuration is PHP

Comment: even you suggest me to perform search on client side ,is ok.whatever , my need is search should be perform even server or client side , so may you give me some code for searching on client side or server side AND Thanks for reply , I am waiting for another reply

Comment: I am strugling for three days for this so pls help me .Thanks

Comment: $(#db_object_state_ + e).html(objectsData[e].data[0].params[state]),

And one more thing is we passing value for jqgrid state column in this way

Comment: The answer of your problem could be easy, The search criteria is posted to the server in certain format - right? Now knowing this format you can easy identify if the search parameters contain the field **state** . In case there is a field **state** replace it with field  **parameters** and pass the parameter object(array) to the search engine.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but i can't understand your concept can you give some example or modify above code pls....

Comment: Question: How you perform the search using the PHP? With simple words - how you get the search parameters comming from the grid?

Comment: I am getting search parmeters  by requesting ajax function to php file and it returns the all data.And one important thing is that is i am loading jqgrid data after load complete by calling function which is called after ajax success parameters. And  in this function definition i am passing values for state column like
 objectsData[e].data[0].params["state"]==Open ?
             (
                $(#db_object_state_+ e).html(Open),
             :
             (
                $(#db_object_state_ + e).html(Close)),

Comment: You do not understand - I speak about your **PHP** code and not to the javascript. So the question: how you get the parameters in the php file - how look the PHP code?

Comment: $params = json_decode($row2[params],true);

            $result[$imei][d][] = array( 
         $lat,
         $lng,
         $altitude,
         $angle,
         $speed,
         $params);  This code from php after sql query and returning this by encoding

Comment: thans for replying , i am waiting for next reply

Comment: In the $params json object find where the field state is present and replace it with the real database name (parameters) to be searched correctly and then pass this object to search in database. I hope you understand the idea.

Comment: i find that variable  but there is already parameters field not state

Comment: pls help me.......

Comment: what happend ? anyone can help

Comment: pls help, i am waiting for your all best beuatifull answers.

Comment: who is there...

Comment: It is really difficult for me to help you since I'm confused to understand your problem. In order to help yourself you should 1. first analyze what is post ted to the server. If the data posted to the server is correct, then 2. you should check your php server code if it returns correct data. This mean when you build the search query you should see what is returned from this query. If the query does not return data this mean that 1. It really there is no data for this query or the query is build ed not correct. In all cases check what is happen search for the problems.